# Unknown Audio-Video Widget/Gadget won't unmute

Tags: windows-10, audio

My system is a Microsoft Surface Pro 7 with the most recent (April 2020) updates. Often when I'm watching a video on an attached screen using the Chrome browser (YouTube, Hulu, etc.), a black gadget/widget pops up in the upper-left part of my computer's screen. It has an audio controller in a vertical rectangular box and right next to it, in a horizontal rectangular box, video playback controls with the name of the video I'm watching.

I have no idea where this thing is coming from or how to close it. But the worst part is that after it opens, it often decides to "slide to mute". By that I mean that I can drag the volume slider up, hold it there with my mouse, and hear sound through my selected speakers/earbuds, but when I let go of the slider, it drops down to mute. Over and over. And after that all of my other audio control options do the same thing.

The only way I've found to unmute the system is to reboot.

Does anyone know what this gadget/widget is? Is it the cause of my "slide to mute" problem? Any way to prevent this?

Comment: why can't you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

By scanning the images returned by a Google search for "windows on screen video controller" I found a post with a picture of this widget/gadget, a thousand other people who wanted to know how to get rid of it, and the process for doing so:

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/7497849

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem again! This time the problem was my own error with a new tablet stand I put the Surface Pro 7 in. The problem was that the clamp on the stand was holding down one edge of the volume button.

This had the same symptoms as before. A gizmo on the screen and a "slide to mute" when I tried to adjust the volume with other controls.

The solution, obviously, was to just move the clamp off the volume button.